# Can I configure Google Now to recognize contacts by their phonetic name?

Tags: google-now, google-voice-actions

I have a lot of friends with names and surnames that Google Now cannot recognize, so I added an entry for their phonetic name.

When I say "Okay, Google" and then "call (phonetic name)", Google successfully transcribes everything, but instead of calling them it will open a search in the browser.

Is there a way to make Google Now recognize my contacts by their phonetic name?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Voice commands for contacts with unusual names](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56300/16575) / [Voice dialling - how to do this?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22006/16575)